# looking for a way to add two sines along two different direction

Tags: matlab, wave

I saw a code online to add two sine waves moving oppositely.

```
x = [0:0.1:2*pi];
w = 1;
for t=0:0.01:10
  f1 = sin(x - w*t);
  f2 = sin(x + w*t);
  f = f1+f2;
  plot(x, f);
  drawnow;
end
```

I am thinking to add two sines but moving at different direction (for example, one going along 30 degree and other going along 90 degree). I read the text and it said the sine wave moving at different direction depends on the wavevector

```
  f1 = sin(kx*x + ky*y - w*t);
  f2 = sin(kx*x + ky*y + w*t);
```

But here there are two variable, x and y, so how do I visualize the wave?

What I am trying to plot is not a sine plate in 3D, but a 3D line. For example, in the following plot, I want to show the 3D curve (in bold red) but not the surface

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to visualize the wave with 3D plot in this case. For example, you can use surf command for this.

```
x = [0:0.1:2*pi];
y = [0:0.1:2*pi];
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
kx=1;
ky=0.5;
w = 1;
for t=0:0.01:10
  f1 = sin(kx*X +ky*Y - w*t);
  f2 = sin(kx*X + ky*Y - w*t);
  f = f1+f2;
  surf(X,Y,f)
  drawnow;
end
```

Update:

If you want two waves not in same direction you will need separate values for wave vector, e.g. for wave going along 30 degree `kx1=sqrt(3)/2, ky1=1/2`, for wave going in 90 degree `kx2=0, ky2=1`.

In addition, if you want wave line instead 3D plate than you can produce slice of sine plate in direction of some selected line.

For example, you want to receive slice in direction 45 degree (x = y).

First step is produce vectors of slice line points:

```
lx = 1/sqrt(2);    % (lx,ly) - direction vector for slice line
ly = 1/sqrt(2);
r = [0:0.1:4*pi];     % parameter to produce line in parametric form
x = lx * r;
y = ly * r;
```

Than we will use these vectors as inputs for sine equations:

```
kx1=sqrt(3)/2;
ky1=0.5;
kx2=0;
ky2=1;
w = 1;
for t=0:0.01:10
  f1 = sin(kx1*x + ky1*y + w*t);
  f2 = sin(kx2*x + ky2*y + w*t);
  f = f1+f2;
  plot(r,f);
  drawnow;
end
```

Of course, form of sine line will depend from direction of slice line and you can receive different waves for different slice directions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is almost what I need. But I am looking for one dimensional sine (not 2D) for f1 and f2, i.e. the wave is on x-y plane but along the given direction, it is just a one-dimensional sine.

Comment: If you are talking about two waves propagating in either direction but along the same line, this can be reduced to 1D case. But you want `(for example, one going along 30 degree and other going along 90 degree)`, this is 2D case and can not be reduced to 1D problem.

Comment: Also you can visualize it as image by replacing the `surf(...` line with `imagesc(f); axis equal; axis tight;`

Comment: well I know it is confusing ... and I know it is 2D not 1D. What I am saying is if I use surf, it gives me a moving sine plate (not sine line). Just like what I shown in the attached figure.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you want. I think it should be easier to "rotate" the directions of the two waves so your direction-of-interest will be exactly along the X-axis. Also if a wave has wavelength `L` (which is always along propagation direction), then wavelength of its cut along the X-axis will be `L*cos(phi)`, where `phi` is the angle between X-axis and the propagation direction (this can be derived geometrically). Then adjust the wavelengths, phases and sum them up.